# How can I start the secure gateway client with a security token?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

Is there a way to start a secure-gateway-client container which takes the token as a parameter?

I'd like to start my container in the background with the 'docker -d' option rather doing it interactively.

I tried starting the container like this:

docker run -d ibmcom/secure-gateway-client

But I still am getting an 401 error in the logs saying I need to specify the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the --t option takes a Security Token as a parameter on the Docker run command.  So, for example:

`docker run -it ibmcom/secure-gateway-client --t <sectoken> <gateway_id>`

Most of the parameters you see in the help can be used on the commandline by using the '--' convention, either the long or short names.  I say most, maxbuffs is not since it may be deprecated.